# Nuxtjs how to use watcher find index changed in v-for

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, nuxt.js, single-page-application

I have a sample code with filteredDates is range date, timeOptionsByDate is range from 18:00 to 00:00

```
<tr v-for="(date, index) in filteredDates" :key="date">
   <select v-model="formData.office_hour[index].time_from">
      <option v-for="time in timeOptionsByDate(date)" :value="time" :key="time">{{ time }}</option>
   </select>
   <select v-model="formData.office_hour[index].time_to">
      <option v-for="time in timeOptionsByDate(date)" :value="time" :key="time">{{ time }}</option>
   </select>
</tr>
```

On watcher

```
watch: {
   'formData.office_hour': {
      deep: true,
      handler: 'handleOfficeHourChange',
    },
}
```

On methods

```
handleOfficeHourChange(newVal, oldVal) {
   const index = this.findChangedIndex(newVal, oldVal)
},
findChangedIndex(newVal, oldVal) {
   for (let i = 0; i < newVal.length; i++) {
      if (!this.isEqual(newVal[i], oldVal[i])) {
         return i;
      }
   }
   return -1;
},
```

When i select time_from, time_to is always -1, wrong index has changed, how to correct above expression